# ChartJS: how to change data in hover box?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Chart is at the bottom of this page:

http://www.coinparator.com/cgqnYQ/

My PHP script is sending X axis values as a unix time stamp. And while I'm generating chart with JS, I'm converting these unix timestamps into a time.

```js
callback: function(dataLabel, index) {
  timezoned = parseInt(dataLabel, 10) * 1000;
  var date = new Date(timezoned);
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
  dataLabel = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
  return index % 2 === 0 ? dataLabel : '';
}
```

As you can se, it works OK. X axis shows time. **However if you hover over any point in the chart (dots on the trendline), it will show you unconverted unix timestamp again.**

How can I show converted time even in hover boxes over trendline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set/override the tooltips option when generating the graph.  I've slightly edited some coffee script code I use in a project to give you an idea of how to achieve this

```
  tooltips:
      mode: 'label'
      callbacks:
        title: (tooltipItem, data) ->
          return [your date conversion function here]
        label: (tooltipItem, data) ->
          return data
```